# Оптимизация игры под IOS

Tags: ios, unity3d, оптимизация, графика, 2d

Знаю,что вопрос гуглится,но большинство статей и советов по правильному(или не особо) переходу с android на ios приложения 2012/2013 года.

Предыстория: Приложение на android весит 120 мб,а на ios почти 300 мб.Все текстуры,которые можно можно было оптимизировать уже оптимизировали,настройки графики "fastest".

> Вопрос: Какие есть способы оптимизации под IOS?

PS если что-то забыл или нужна доп инфа,то пишите в комментарии.

UPD: format RGB Compressed PVRTC 2 bits

Comment: Эм) fastest подразумевает минимальный уровень компресии) Вариант с загрузкой бандлов, рассматривали?

Comment: да,как раз разбираюсь с ними сейчас,но хотелось бы узнать,есть ли еще варианты @ЕгорБашинский

Comment: Координально - только бандлы. Кое что можно спихнуть на [OnDemandResourse](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/) ,но надо учитывать что это будет перекачиватся каждый раз . Единственное что могу порекомендовать , внимательно просмотреть едитор лог билда. На определенном этапе там  выводится статистика занимаего места ресурсами(текстуры музыка). Это может подксказать что оптимизировать.

Comment: Начинать надо с выяснения, какие данные занимают сколько места. А то вы жали жали текстуры и внезапно выяснится, что там рантайм на 150 мб.

Comment: Текстуры самая проблемная точка,было 300 мб почти,после сжатия осталось 172 мб. Нужен результат в 150 мб. @VTT